# cURL failing to exactly simulate HTTP Post

Tags: php, email, http, post, curl

I'm an old school COBOL programmer who is delving more and more into the usage of PHP on my websites/pages.  I've learned quite a bit, but have a new challenge which CURL should solve.

So far, I've not managed to get my code to work as required, so I'll try to explain clearly what I want it to do and show examples below.

I've lifted the form code from an Internet affiliate business's own capture page to fit it into my own full screen video capture page.  Basically I host my video capture page on my server, but the form interacts with the affiliate business's server - thus giving me control over the look and feel at the front end (my server), but utilising the functionality of the affiliate business at the back end (their server).

This setup works perfectly well, with the form submitting the prospects details with a simple HTTP post as shown below..

```
<form action="http://<?php displayID(""); ?>.affiliate-business.com/index#form" method="post" name="PRE">
<input name="ENROLLER" value="<?php displayID2(""); ?>" type="hidden">
<input name="SOURCE" value="<?php echo $_GET['SOURCE']; ?>" type="hidden">
<input name="ENROLLER_NAME" value="<?php displayID3(""); ?>" type="hidden">
<input name="PAGE" value="11" type="hidden">
<input name="LANGUAGE" value="en" type="hidden">
<input type="hidden" name="STP" value="save">
<input name="FNAME" size="36" maxlength="40" value="" type="text" placeholder="First Name" required><br><br>
<input name="LNAME" size="36" maxlength="40" value="" type="text" placeholder="Last Name" required><br><br>
<input name="EMAIL" size="36" maxlength="60" value="" type="text" placeholder="E-mail" required><br><br>
<input name="PHONE" size="36" maxlength="40" value="" type="text" placeholder="Phone (*Optional)"><br><br>
<input type="image" src="http://example-image.png" alt="Reserve My Position Now!">
</form>
```

This correctly results in the following 3 actions..
-1- Notifies me of the subscriber by email  (business's sever)
-2- Welcomes the subscriber by email and executes an email follow-up series  (business's sever)
-3- Redirects them immediately to a start page (business's sever)

OK, so now to my attempt at being clever.

I want to not only submit the form data to the affiliate business's server, but to also send my own personal email to the subscribing prospect when the from submit button is clicked.

So I essentially want two actions from one submit button.

My solution was to introduce a PHP file to handle both the sending of the personal email using the PHP mail function and the submission of the form fields/data using CURL.

Below is both my HTTP form code from my video capture page and the subsequent PHP code in the actioned PHP file..

```
<form action="sbcmail.php" method="post" name="PRE">
<input name="ENROLLER" value="<?php displayID2(""); ?>" type="hidden">
<input name="SOURCE" value="<?php echo $_GET['SOURCE']; ?>" type="hidden">
<input name="ENROLLER_NAME" value="<?php displayID3(""); ?>" type="hidden">
<input name="PAGE" value="11" type="hidden">
<input name="LANGUAGE" value="en" type="hidden">
<input type="hidden" name="STP" value="save">
<input type="hidden" name="URL" value="http://<?php displayID(""); ?>.affiliate-business.com/index#form">
<input name="FNAME" size="36" maxlength="40" value="" type="text" placeholder="First Name" required><br><br>
<input name="LNAME" size="36" maxlength="40" value="" type="text" placeholder="Last Name" required><br><br>
<input name="EMAIL" size="36" maxlength="60" value="" type="text" placeholder="E-mail" required><br><br>
<input name="PHONE" size="36" maxlength="40" value="" type="text" placeholder="Phone (*Optional)"><br><br>
<input type="image" src="http://payspreesniper.com/sbc/reserve-my-position-now.png" alt="Reserve My Position Now!">
</form>
```

sbcmail.php:

```
$to = "to@email.com";
$subject = "SBC Opt-in";
$msg = "This is my message" . " " . $_POST["URL"];
$headers = "From: from@email.com" . "\r\n";
/* ."CC: cc@email.com";*/
mail($to,$subject,$msg,$headers);

$url = $_POST["URL"];
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
$params = array(
    "ENROLLER"=>$_POST["ENROLLER"],
    "SOURCE"=>$_POST["SOURCE"],
    "ENROLLER_NAME"=>$_POST["ENROLLER_NAME"],
    "PAGE"=>$_POST["PAGE"],
    "LANGUAGE"=>$_POST["LANGUAGE"],
    "STP"=>$_POST["STP"],
    "FNAME"=>$_POST["FNAME"],
    "LNAME"=>$_POST["LNAME"],
    "EMAIL"=>$_POST["EMAIL"],
    "PHONE"=>$_POST["_POST"],
);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,"$url");
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTREDIR, 3);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,http_build_query($params));
var_dump($returned_content);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo $result;
print_r($result);
echo "returned content: " . $returned_content;
curl_close($ch);
```

And this is the result on my web page sbcmail.php:

### 302 Found:

NULL

Found

The document has moved here.

Found

The document has moved here.

returned content:

---

The actions that either occurred (or not) were as follows..
-1- Notifies me of the subscriber by email (business's sever)
-2- Fails to welcome the subscriber by email (business's sever)
-3- Fails to redirect to the start page (business's sever)
-4- Correctly sends my personal email (my sever)

So the subscribing prospect was not automatically redirected to the start page and did not receive the welcome email or any of the series of follow-up emails.

Now I can handle the redirect to the start page with a PHP redirect (excluded form this example) as I already have the URL stored in $URL.

But, I don't know why the standard HTTP post manages to invoke the welcome email and follow up series to the subscriber and my CURL version from sbcmail.php does not?

Clearly there is a difference in the information delivered to the server via the standard from code and my PHP code.  I would appreciate any help or advice as to what that might be.. it's the last piece required to complete my puzzle.

Why is NULL displayed?  Why do I get a 302?  Why does the business's server not send the expected email(s) to the subscribing prospect's email address?

OK, I'll stop waffling and cross my fingers that one of you very clever bods can show me what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks in advance,

Kevin

---

Change of tactic as suggested by one of you wonderful folk.

I now call my sbcmail.php file from Javascript, which has solved the sending of the HTML form directly and executing my PHP code when the submit button on the form is clicked.

But this has presented another problem.

Here is the JS call from the capture page..

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function submit(clicked)
{
load('sbcmail.php');
}
</script>
```

Here is the PHP code in sbcmail.php...

```
<?php 
$to = "to@email.com"; 
$subject = "SBC Opt-in"; 
$msg = "This is my message" . " " . $_POST["URL"]; 
$headers = "From: from@email.com" . "\r\n" ."CC: cc@email.com"; mail($to,$subject,$msg,$headers); 

$redirect = "affiliate-business.com/login?EMAIL="; . $_POST["EMAIL"] . "&LOGIN=1"; header("Location: $redirect"); 
die(); 
?>
```

The new problem is that the PHP mail doesn't work when I submit the form on the capture page, but the redirect does work, so I know JS is successfully calling sbcmail.php.

When I visit sbcmail.php directly, the PHP mail does work as does the redirect.

So, does anyone have any ideas?? Is the JS call missing something?

Sorry to be a pain, but I'm oh so close to the result I set out to achieve.

Comment: The cURL code looks good for the most part.  `NULL` is displayed because the variable `$returned_content` you are var_dump'ing does not exist.  `$result` is the returned content from cURL.  The form submission to the 3rd party will fail because `$_POST` is an associative array, so all the lines you have like `$_POST-"FNAME"-,` are not doing what you'd expect.  Instead you need to use `$_POST['FNAME']`, `$_POST['ENROLLER']` etc.  Hope that helps.

Comment: where were you in y2k? can i take a guess and say florida? hehe :p

Comment: My KISS suggestion would be to call a JS function at form submission that triggers your own 'send personal email' script, which does only that. While keeping the form POST directly to the business server. So flow would be: User submits form. Your Send Personal Email Script Begins Execution. The Form is POSTed to the business server.

Comment: @Empathy, many thanks for your response.  For a moment I didn't realise what you were taking about.  You point about $_POST-"FNAME"- is correct, except that you only see that in my question because I did a global edit of "[" and "]" to get the question posted and didn't realise.  so in actual fact my code is like this ...$_POST['FNAME'] .

Comment: @Empathy, Sorry to have confused things.  I know the details are reaching the server because I can log in and see the information in my back office contact manager, but the main problem is, the subscriber is not receiving the welcome email or follow ups and I assume it's something to do with the receiving server not getting the info in a particular format or even a potentially a piece of missing information. In your experience, does my post via my PHP page mirror the post directly from my HTML?  And re your JS function ID (I know nothing about JS), isn't that what I am doing now, but via PHP?

Comment: Just a side note: You may want to mask output towards HTML by using [htmlspecialchars()](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars).

Comment: @DaSourcerer - Thanks for the suggestion, although you're assuming I know more than I do.  Where or how exactly would you suggest I use that in my code (remember, I'm no PHP expert, just picking up a little knowledge as I go).

Comment: @Kevin Not meaning to offend you, but … surely as COBOL coder you have learned to sanitize input and mask output? As an example something like `<?php displayID3(""); ?>` should change into `<?php htmlspecialchars(displayID3("")); ?>`

Comment: @Kevin, I'm a bit stumped too. Try writing your parameters to a file to ensure they are properly being set. But also, to answer two of your questions: `Why is NULL displayed?` Null is getting displayed when you twice print `$returned_content` -- which is null as it was never set (your curl response data is saved in `$result = curl_exec($ch);`.... `Why do I get a 302?` You get a 302 because the external server has a redirect on the url. the browser follows this automatically, and i assume your script is doing so too since the external server is receiving at least some of the data.

Comment: @DaSourcerer, thanks - please consider that PHP is like Chinese to me, so htmlspecialchars meant nothing to me - I should look it up so I know what it does (and I will), but just responded promptly.  Not sure that my lack of knowledge about PHP functions bares much relevance to my past days in COBOL, but.. each to his own.

Comment: @Empathy, thanks.. I spotted you'd original answered the NULL issue (or non-issue).  We know the server is receiving info by the fact the subscribers details are registered in my contact manager and I receive an email notification.  What's stumping me is why the POST from PHP doesn't behave like the  HTML POST.

Comment: @Empathy, actually last night I did write my output:  1ENROLLER3009499SOURCEtestENROLLER_NAMEPaySpree SniperPAGE11LANGUAGEenSTPsaveURLhttp://payspreesniper.sbcpowerline.com/index#formFNAMEPeterLNAMEBrownEMAILmobilbo29@gmail.comPHONEx62y20 (which all looks good) - so this is why I think something, somewhere esle is awry.

Comment: @Kevin you are injecting variable output into essentially another language. You have to be careful not to inject any elements that have syntactical meaning in said language, possibly breaking it. That's what `htmlentities()` is good for: It masks any of those elements in a way that they no longer have any syntactical meaning while being adequately represented. Surely you have done similar things when connecting to SQL databases?

Comment: @DaSourcerer, Thanks for the explanation - not knowing PHP I was unaware of what it's function was, so it's good to have your input.  This certainly gives me something to test with - I'll see if that changes the result.  Beyond that I am contacting the company owner who is accessible and will ask him to advise what their system is expecting.

Comment: @love, I've gone with your KISS suggestion, calling my sbcmail.php file from JS and everything is working, including the redirect to the start page, but not the PHP mail function (code below)..      <?php

    $to = "to@email.com";
    $subject = "SBC Opt-in";
    $msg = "This is my message" . " " . $_POST["URL"];
    $headers = "From: from@email.com" . "\r\n" ."CC: cc@email.com";
mail($to,$subject,$msg,$headers);

    $redirect = "http://www.affiliate-business.com/login?EMAIL=" . $_POST["EMAIL"] . "&LOGIN=1";
    header("Location: $redirect");
    die();
    ?>   Any ideas?

Comment: @Kevin problem is that you are not actually POSTing data to the PHP script. Please see me answer.

Comment: @Kevin I actually doubt this is the culprit of your issues. It is just something that caught my eye as I am a bit of a burnt child when it comes to injection attacks. May I recommend [PHP: The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) to you?

Answer (score 0):

As a followup to the JS implementation, here is what that code should look like using jQuery. Note, to use jQuery you just need to include it in your HTML head:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Code:

```
// Listen For Form Submit:
$('form').submit(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();                     //Stop the form from submitting temporarily. 
  $.post('sbcmail.php', $(this).serialize()); //Load data from the form and POST to php script.
  $(this).submit();                           //Now submit the form normally. 
});
```

This performs an actual POST to the PHP script along with the form data. We don't care about the response data from the PHP script (most likely), we just want to trigger it, and move on with the default form submission.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @love, but still have the same problem with the PHP mail function not working unless I visit the page directly.  I've even tried window.location.href=*.sbcmail.php, but still no mail.  So I'm inclined to think it's something to do with the JS call.. almost like it's not actually calling the sbcmail.php file.

Comment: @Kevin you need to perform a POST to your sbcmail script since that's how it is loading data. I think the POST paramaters may be case-sensitive too. Does your mail script work if you run it manually from the CLI with hardcoded values? Also, is sbcmail located in the same directory as your form? The 'redirect' you experience should actually be a redirect to wherever the form is being POSTed to.

Comment: @ Love, thanks and yes the capture page and sbcmail.php are in the same dir.  I actually think that the redirect is not required as the JS is doing what it's supposed to in terms of submitting the form normally via HTML POST - I proved this by removing the redirect from sbcmail.php (still no mail, but still the start page loaded. This is why I think sbcmail is not being invoked with the JS call.

Comment: @Kevin You are correct that the PHP redirect is not required. What this JS method does is that basically just executes the PHP script, and then moves on to submitting the form normally, following whatever action that the form is designated to do. In this JS, comment out the `$(this).submit();` so we don't submit the form. Now you should open up your browser developer tools, and go to the Network tab. (In Chrome: RightClick -> Inspect -> Network). Now submit the form, and look in the Network tab for that request. Here you can see if you receive back a 200 success code or not.

Comment: @Kevin I'm happy to help walk you through this via live chat. Comment here when you work on this again and we coordinate a discussion.

Comment: that's very much appreciated.. thank you.  I've actually found another solution however, with an interim page that enables me to give the subscriber more important/enticing info and encourages them to click for instant access.  By hiding all the form fields (pre-populated with values from the capture page), their click will in fact forward them to the start page and if not, they will have the personal email inviting them to do just that (2 bites at the cherry).